# Proof of exponential family quality

Tags: statistics

The exponential family of probability density functions take the form

$f(y,\theta, \phi) = \exp \bigg\{ \frac{y\theta - b(\theta)}{a(\phi)}  + c(y, \phi) \bigg\}$. I know that
$$ E(\frac{\partial \text{log-likelihood of }f}{\partial \theta}) = 0$$.

I've tried to prove it, but I don't understand how one could take the expected value of a partial derivative.  How would I prove this?

Edit:

In more detail, the expected value is given by

$$ \int \frac{\partial \log L}{\partial \theta} g $$

integrated over the domain of $\frac{\partial \log L}{\partial \theta}$ and where $g$ is the density of $\frac{\partial \log L}{\partial \theta}$. I'm not sure how to find $g$ and solve this integral.

Comment: Get the expected value by multiplying it by the density and integrating over the domain. So $\int (\partial \log L / \partial \theta) f$.

Comment: yes, but I'm not sure how to simplify it so that it is equal to 0.

Comment: I can't say I've seen this relation before. Have a reference you could share?